# Remove all VBA modules from excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to remove all VBA modules from an Excel file using VBA?

The names of the modules if they exist at all are unknowns before running this script.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obviously, you can. The following code will do the job:

```
Sub compact_code()

On Error Resume Next
    Dim Element As Object
    For Each Element In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove Element
    Next

End Sub
```

This will remove all modules including ClassModules and UserForms but keep all object modules (sheets, workbook).

Comment: The funny thing is that in this situation it's not required to iterate from last to first when looping which is usually required when running any deletion process. All modules, userforms and class modules are removed.

Comment: I would change the reference to `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` or an specific workbook reference if I'm going to change another workbook's code.

Comment: @pablete watch out when you have this in a template tho: `ThisWorkbook` will refer to the template, not the project itself. This can be tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar alternative that removes only the ClassModules:

```
On Error Resume Next
With wbk.VBProject
    For x = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
        If .VBComponents(x).Type = vbext_ct_StdModule Then
            .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(x)
        End If
    Next x
End With
On Error GoTo 0
```