# Is there a way to delete macro in excel programmatically?

Tags: java, c#, excel, apache-poi

We have macro in excel.We want macro to be deleted programmatically.
Is there a way to delete macro in excel programmatically?

**<sup>Updated from the OP's comments</sup>**

We need to accomplish below task :

1. User fill data in excel(.xls or .xlsx) which has macro.
2. User validate data through macro.
3. Application then import that excel however before processing it need to delete that macro.

Comment: have you tried saving the  file as xls/xlsx? (if that feature exist.)

Comment: Thanks redflar3 for suggestion.Could you please elaborate what will happen if we save it as xls.xlsx ? 

We need to accomplish below task :
 
  1. User fill data in excel(.xls or .xlsx) which has macro.
  2. User validate data through macro.
  3. Application then import that excel however before processing it need to delete that macro.

Comment: First of all your file should be xlsm in order to contain macro.. If you save such a file as xls/xlsx, you can strip out the macro..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518493/remove-all-vba-modules-from-excel-file)?

Comment: Seems to be a similar but not same question. I am also interested how to remove marcros from excel in java but not in vba.