# Error "subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to auto delete all VBA modules present in personal workbook, I am trying below code but this is showing an error 9 saying "subscript out of range "
Please help me to solve this error

```
Sub deletemodule()
    Dim vbCom As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 10
        On Error GoTo abc
        Set vbCom = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
        vbCom.Remove vbComponent:=vbCom.Item("Module" & i)
    Next
abc:
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: On the Set, or the .Remove line?

Comment: Are you running an international version of Excel? The module default names differ in different versions. Verify that your modules have names following the Module*X* syntax.

Comment: This might be helpfull? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518493/remove-all-vba-modules-from-excel-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try to revert loop:

```
For i = 10 To 2 step -1
On Error GoTo abc
Set vbCom = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
vbCom.Remove vbComponent:=vbCom.Item("Module" & i)
Next
```

Comment: how can i add screen shot here pls help

Comment: I'm not suggesting to change the name but to revert loop. I guess you are trying to remove item from collection which is not there anymore. If you remove item no. 2 then there is no more item no. 10 as it was moved to position no. 9. etc...

Comment: I agree but in this situation name of the module will not be changed & will remains the same as before "module10" only position will be changed from no 10 to no 9.

Comment: there may be a solution if I could count no of modules available so then upper limit of i will be set to that no. I think so not sure ...

Comment: see the link proposed by @JvdV presenting the other answer of mine or alternative one with `.count` being similar to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code removes all Standard & Class modules from the workbook.
Note sure what other types there will be - Chart sheets, forms, macro sheets(?)

Modules are a collection so you can step through them using a `For...Each` loop rather than needing to know how many or what they're called beforehand.

```
Public Sub DeleteAllModules()

    Dim vbcom As Object
    Dim vMod As Object

    Set vbcom = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents

    For Each vMod In vbcom
        Select Case vMod.Type
            Case 1, 2 'Standard & Class modules
                vbcom.Remove vMod
            Case 100 'Sheet & ThisWorkbook modules
                'Do nothing
        End Select
    Next vMod

End Sub
```